# Why does apt-get NOT use 100% (cpu OR disk OR net)?

Tags: apt, cpu-usage

Why does `apt-get` *not* use 100% of either cpu, disk, or network -- or even close to it? Even on a slow system (Raspberry Pi 2+) I'm getting at most 30% CPU load. I'm just thinking that either it's being artificially throttled, or it should max out *something* while it's working ... or it should be able to do its thing faster than it does.

Edit: I'm just measuring roughly via cpu/disk/net monitors in my panel, and the System Monitor app of Ubuntu MATE.

Please explain why I'm wrong. :-)

Update: I understand that `apt-get` needs to fetch its updates (and may be limited by upstream/provider bandwidth). But once it's "unpacking" and so on, the CPU usage should at least *go up* (if not max out). On my fairly decent home workstation, which uses an SSD for its main drive, and a ramdisk for /tmp, this is not the case.

Or maybe I need to take a closer look.

Comment: How are you measuring disk and network load?

Comment: Disk IO is just like network IO, though. It will still block the app, preventing it from using the CPU. Alas, `apt-get` isn't particularly good at optimizing this. I imagine it could install as it downloads so that by the time your download is finished most of your payload could already be installed, but, unfortunately, it doesn't.  In any case, standalone installs mostly just extract data to disk. Those operations are inherently IO bound, and there's simply not much else to do but wait on the disk drive to finish reading or writing.

Comment: How did you get the *30% CPU load* number?

Comment: @PSkocik "I imagine it could install as it downloads" apt-get just downloads, dpkg installs. And dpkg is smarter than apt-get in the order that a bunch of packages should be installed, which may not be the same that apt-get downloads them.

Comment: Note that an application which is 100% CPU bound for half a tick, and then 100% IO-bound for the other half will appear neither CPU-bound nor IO-bound,.

Comment: @Braiam: A hypothetical `apt-get` that's smart enough to pipeline `dpkg` installs would know which packages to download first (those without additional dependencies). As apt-get understand dependencies, and the dependency graph is acyclic, there is always one package which can be installed first, and this should be downloaded first.

Comment: @MSalters at which point you wonder, why should two simple straightforwards tools over-complicate a process, when even the maintainer has other [more important (and high impact) things to do](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~cjwatson/blog/no-more-hash-sum-mismatch-errors.html)?

Comment: @Braiam: At my previous company we reused `dpkg` and had to rewrite it, for use on embedded systems where we couldn't afford the disk overhead of downloading every package before installing it. This meant we needed 3x the disk space: old install, new packages, new install. Our integrated tool could stream the packages, install them on the fly, and was smart enough to handle the few exceptions (kernel updates & the tool itself, mainly).A real problem with the Linux philosophy of "2 tasks, 2 programs" is avoidable communication overhead.

Comment: You could try apt-fast. It might speed up the download portion of the task, but it probably wouldn't affect the rest.

Comment: Everything using the CPU always uses 100% of the CPU, for a short period of time.  If that "period" is a third of a second, then we say it used the CPU 33% of the time.  So if a process spends some time on the CPU, some time waiting on net and some waiting on disk, that will basically make up (approximately - there are other resources and processes can wait for other processes or for a resource to become available), the whole.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apps will only max out the CPU if the app is *CPU-bound*.
An app is *CPU-bound* if it can quickly get all of its data and what it waits on is the processor to process the data.

`apt-get`, on the other hand, is *IO-bound*. That means it can process its data rather quickly, but loading the data (from disk or from the network) takes time, during which the processor can do either other stuff or sit idle if no other processes need it.

Typically, all IO requests (disk, network) are slow, and whenever an application thread makes one, the kernel will remove it from the processor until the data gets loaded into the kernel (=these IO requests are called *blocking requests*).

Comment: With `apt` commands, it's aggravated by the fact that many files are open in sync mode, or with frequent explicit flushes to disk being requested to guarantee data on disk stays in a consistent state as a system crash could have serious consequences otherwise. Running `apt` commands with `eatmydata` can often dramatically improve performance at the expense of reduced reliability (not to mention that services started as part of package installations will inherit the eatmydata settings)

Comment: Lol at that last point :).  Does anyone have numbers for eatmydata since the 2010 commit in https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=578635 ?  I don't know if "dramatically" is the right word still.

Comment: Ah, maybe it is (at least on some cloud providers) https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1236531/comments/6

Comment: @sourcejedi On a Raspberry Pi2 with a relatively high-end SD card (but still an SD card, not a high-end SSD), I consider “dramatically” to be a bit of an understatement. The performance of dpkg on flash media really sucks.

Comment: If it's disk-IO-bound then why is it not using 100% disk bandwidth?

Comment: @immibis IO bound doesn't necessarily mean that the process wants to do huge amounts of IO, it simply says that it's not really doing many computations and *most* of its work is reading/writing to disk. In any case if you want an answer is that the OS has schedulers and buffers precisely to avoid one process taking over all the system. If you want a system where you can define a process as X-bound and be sure it will use 100% during operation you have to move to systems without multitasking.

Comment: Because you can't really define 100% disk bandwidth. Even solid state drives have varying performance across various file or stripe sizes.

Comment: When I use apt on a system running in RAM, I surely reach 100% CPU with apt-get. It can't take advantage of multiple CPUs though (no multi-threading).

Answer (score 16):

> Even on a slow system (Raspberry Pi 2+) I'm getting at most 30% CPU load.

The Raspberry Pi 2+ has 4 cores. For some monitoring tools, a 100% usage correspond to all the cores been used at 100%. If only one core in a quad code processor is used, the CPU load is 25 %. The 30% CPU load you mention is roughly one core used at 100% while some processes are running on the other cores:

```
(100% on one core out of 4 = 100 / 4 = 25%) + some processes ≃ 30%
```

Since `apt-get` is not multi threaded, it will never use more than one processor, which is 25% of all the CPU resources.

---

Here is an example on my 8 cores (4 cores with [Hyper-Threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)) machine running Ubuntu, I launched one thread with the `cat /dev/zero > /dev/null` command in order to create an infinite process that utilize one core entirely.

Now if we take a look at the graph from [`htop`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop), we can see that the average load (`Avg` bar) is `12.7%`, which correspond to one core used at 100%, which is also 1/8 of all the CPU resources:

```
(100% = 100 / 8 = 12.5%) + some background processes ≃ 12.7%.
```

[image: htop]

It can also be noted that the command has a value of `100%` in the `CPU%` column, this is because it's relative to one core and not to all the cores.

Comment: +1, a usage % close to a multiple of (100 / nCores) should always trigger further scrutiny. This can be checked - and indeed is precluded - by using a monitor able to show usage per core, where 0 <= the% <= 100 * nCores

Comment: Isn't `/dev/zero > /dev/null` a better example, since urandom will deplete the entropy pool?

Comment: @FilipHaglund `cat /dev/zero > /dev/null` gives the same result, I didn't know that device, thanks. *urandom will deplete the entropy pool* I don't know the entropy pool, how can it be a problem?

Comment: When programs use crypto, they need truly random data to generate secure encryption keys. The computer generates entropy by watching the mouse move among other things. There are hardware random number generators, but most computers don't have them. If the entropy is all used up, the code that needs secure entropy has to wait for more to be generated. Urandom will use truly random bits if available, or otherwise return less secure random bits.

Comment: *When programs use crypto* Even if I think that nobody will perform a CPU benchmark while generating a random key, I've updated my answer as a precaution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're actually not measuring IO %.  I haven't seen a Linux IO% widget.  (I'm very envious of the Windows 10 task manager :).  Check using the `iotop` command and you will see 100% IO.

`top` should show 100% across `user`+`system`+`iowait`, for values of 100% divided by your core count as described by A.L.  I'm not saying `top` is 100% helpful, but it can be a really useful all-around tool to learn.

*Throughput* will be lower than maximum, because you're unpacking lots of small files, aka "random IO".  There's also some disk sync / cache flushes, although since 2010 on Linux there's only a few of them for each package installed.  ([Used to be one per file](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=578635)).

Comment: Use `iotop --only`, the `--only` option *only show processes or threads actually doing I/O*.

Comment: iostat, dstat, atop... will show per disk disk utilisation without needing privileges. It's for the per-task utilisation that you need privileges

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas absolutely correct. The point I was trying to make (ninja edit) is that the OP mentions a couple of GUI tools.  And the particular GUI tools I've seen, like Gnome System Monitor, show throughput but no IO%.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, IO/Network requests are really slow compared to CPU ops. This means that while your network card is fetching data, or your disk is writing this data, your CPU does absolutly nothing (for this process anyway).

If your hard drive is speeder than your network connection (which is probably true), it won't write more than it has received.

Finally, the network percentage corresponds to the max possible network **card** usage, not connection. So you may have a 1Gb/s network adapter, you're really unlikely to have an internet connection that reaches this bandwidth.